# As3 creating and using external classes

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, class

I'm new to flash, as3 and this forum so any help would be great!

I've made an xml gallery, all the movieclips and everything have been created dynamically and the images are being loaded through an xml file. Except two buttons which are in the library and have the linkage names next_btn and prev_btn.

Now what I want to do is, I have 3 categories of galleries, so I want to convert my script into a class which I can use for every type of gallery.  (I hope I'm being clear)

When the user clicks on gallery, a the function **startGallery()** is called.

I need to know how to go about it I'm pretty much clueless, I've read a WHOLE LOT of tutorials about classes but I really can't understand how to do this.  I would really appreciate any help, thank you! :)

Here's my code:

```
    //declaring variables
var _array:Array;
var _lastX:Number;
var _lastWidth:Number;
var _length:Number;
var _firstWidth:Number;
var _widths:Array;
var _names:Array;
var _sizes:Array;
var container_mc:MovieClip;
var my_images:XMLList;
var count:Number = 0;
var full_mc:MovieClip
var currentWidth:Number;
var scrollCounter:Number = 0;
var rect:Shape;
var nameLabel:TextField = new TextField();
var sizeLabel:TextField = new TextField();
var myFont = new Font1;
var format:TextFormat;

var myXmlLoader:URLLoader;
var myRequest:URLRequest;

var next_mc = new next_btn;
var prev_mc = new prev_btn;

    //function called when user clicks on gallery link
function startGallery():void{
myXmlLoader = new URLLoader();
myRequest = new URLRequest("gallery.xml");
myXmlLoader.load(myRequest);
myXmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXml);
}

    //getting all the xml info
function processXml(e:Event):void{
var myXml:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
_length = myXml.IMAGE.length();
_firstWidth = myXml.@FIRSTWIDTH;
currentWidth = _firstWidth;
my_images = myXml.IMAGE;

_array = new Array(_length);
_names = new Array(_length);
_sizes = new Array(_length);
var i:int = 0;
var j:int = 0;
var k:int = 0;
var l:int = 0;

for each(var path:String in myXml.IMAGE.@THUMB){
    _array[i++] = path;
}

_widths = new Array(_length);
for each(var size:Number in myXml.IMAGE.@WIDTH){
    _widths[j++] = size;
}
for each(var names:String in myXml.IMAGE.@NAME){
    _names[k++] = names;
}
for each(var sizes:String in myXml.IMAGE.@SIZE){
    _sizes[l++] = sizes;
}
//both methods produce the same result
/*for(var i:int = 0; i<_length; i++){
    _array[i] = myXml.IMAGE[i].@THUMB;
}*/

createContainer();
callThumbs();
}

    //creates the main movieclip the holds all the stuff - container_mc
function createContainer():void{
container_mc = new MovieClip();
container_mc.name = "container_mc";
addChild(container_mc);
//container_mc.alpha = 0;
//container_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
//container_mc.mouseChildren = false;
container_mc.x = ((stage.stageWidth-_firstWidth)/2);
container_mc.y = 110;
container_mc.buttonMode = true;
container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
}


    //loades the thumbnails
function callThumbs():void{
if(_array.length>0){
    var loader:Loader = new Loader;
    //addChild(loader);

    //var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_array[0]);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbsLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(_array[0]));
    trace(_array[0]);
    trace(_names[0]);
    loader.x = _lastX + _lastWidth + 3;
    loader.name = String(count);

    _lastX = loader.x;
    _array.shift();
    trace(loader.name);
    count++;
}
}

function thumbsLoaded(e:Event):void{
_lastWidth = e.target.width;
var myThumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
container_mc.addChild(myThumb);
myThumb.alpha = 0;
TweenLite.to(myThumb, 1, {alpha:0.5, ease:Strong.easeOut, onComplete:callButtons});
callThumbs();
}

    //once the thumbnails are loaded, the buttons are created
function callButtons():void{
//buttons & info
if(count == _length){
    next_mc.x = _firstWidth;
    next_mc.y = 125;
    next_mc.alpha = 0.7;
    container_mc.addChild(next_mc);
    prev_mc.x = MovieClip(root).x;
    prev_mc.y = 125;
    prev_mc.alpha = 0.3;
    container_mc.addChild(prev_mc);


    initTextFields();

}
}

    //initialising the textfields containing information about each thumbnail
function initTextFields():void{
//all the textfields are initialised here
}

    //loads the full images when a thumbnail is clicked
function callFull(e:MouseEvent):void{
if(scrollCounter == e.target.name){
var full_loader:Loader = new Loader();
var full_url = my_images[e.target.name].@FULL;
full_loader.load(new URLRequest(full_url));
full_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, fullLoaded);

container_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFull);
TweenLite.to(container_mc, 1, {colorTransform:{tint:0xffffff, tintAmount:0.7}, ease:Strong.easeOut});
TweenLite.to(navBar_mc, 1, {colorTransform:{tint:0xffffff, tintAmount:0.7}, ease:Strong.easeOut});
navBar_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
navBar_mc.mouseChildren = false;

container_mc.buttonMode = false;
}
}

function fullLoaded(e:Event):void{
full_mc = new MovieClip();
full_mc.buttonMode = true;
addChild(full_mc);
var my_loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
full_mc.addChild(my_loader);
my_loader.alpha = 0;
TweenLite.to(my_loader, 1, {alpha:1, ease:Strong.easeOut});
my_loader.x = (stage.stageWidth - my_loader.width)/2;
my_loader.y = (stage.stageHeight - my_loader.height)/2;
my_loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,removeFull);
}

    //removes the full images once the user closes the image
function removeFull(e:MouseEvent):void{
//removed the full image
}



function scrollOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {alpha:1, ease:Strong.easeOut});
}

function scrollOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
TweenLite.to(e.currentTarget, 1, {alpha:0.7, ease:Strong.easeOut});
}

function scrollClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
//the container_mc is moved left/right when the next/previous buttons are clicked
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is really broad. Do you think you could break it up into some smaller specific questions about the problems you are having?

Answer (score 0):

To have an item in your library backed by an external .as file first make a class file, which are generally laid out something like:

```
package {

  import flash.display.MovieClip;

  public class GalleryClassName extends MovieClip {

    //Put reusable variables here
    private var someThingUsedInMultipleFunctions:String = "hello";

    public function GalleryClassName() {
      //Constructor, in this case it will be called automatically
    }

    //Put additional functions here
    private function additionalFunction() {
      //Do stuff
    }

    //Load a gallery
    public function startGallery(xmlPath:String) {
      //start loading the specified XML file
      ...
      myRequest = new URLRequest(xmlPath);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your library right click > properties > and export/link and enter your "GalleryClassName". This should link the code file with the library object.

If you want to make a reusable class you would determine what variables would be different between the 3 galleries and store them in the class in the "reusable" section. the lazy man's way is to make the variables `public` instead of `private` and access from outside the class like `GalleryClassName.someThingUsedInMultipleFunctions = "dude";`. If you want, you can also look into passing arguments as well as getters and setters.

Edit

To use this class in your .fla code:

```
//Assuming you do not have an instance already on the stage:
var gal:GalleryClassName = new GalleryClassName();
gal.x = 50; //Place it wherever you want
gal.y = 50;
addChild(gal);
```

Then load the gallery xml

```
gal.startGallery("somepath/gallery1.xml");
```

Comment: Hi ToddBFisher thanks for the quick reply :)

Though your answer did help me (yeah I was confused about that too), I don't think my question was clear
Basically my script creates a container_mc which holds all the thumbnails and everything.

Now, how would I go about using this class from my .fla? As in, do I have to create objects of the class or can I just call the startGallery() function like I did earlier?  And as for passing arguments I guess I could pass some xml details to tell the class which gallery to load?